# Spark SQL ignoring dynamic partition filter value

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Running into an issue on Spark 2.4 on EMR 5.20 in AWS.

I have a string column as a partition, which has date values. My goal is to have the max value of this column be referenced as a filter. The values look like this `2019-01-01` for January 1st, 2019.

In this query, I am trying to filter to a certain date value (which is a string data type), and Spark ends up reading all directories, not just the resulting `max(value)`.

```
spark.sql("select mypartitioncolumn, column1, column2 from mydatabase.mytable where mypartitioncolumn= (select max(mypartitioncolumn) from myothertable) group by 1,2,3 ").show
```

However, in this instance, If I hardcode the value, it only reads the proper directory.

```
spark.sql("select mypartitioncolumn, column1, column2 from mydatabase.mytable where mypartitioncolumn= '2019-01-01' group by 1,2,3 ").show
```

Why is Spark not recognizing both methods in the same way? I made sure that if I run the `select max(mypartitioncolumn) from myothertable` query, it shows the exact same value as my hardcoded method (as well as the same datatype).

I can't find anything in the documentation that differentiates partition querying other than data type differences. I checked to make sure that my schema in both the source table as well as value are string types, and also tried to cast my value as a string as well `cast( (select max(mypartitioncolumn) from myothertable) as string)`, it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Please refer solution mentioned in below links and let me know if it works. I have tested it in spark while reading partitions from Hive partitioned table which is partitioned on date column.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40663066/how-to-load-only-the-data-of-the-last-partition/57440645#57440645 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55053218/pyspark-getting-latest-partition-from-hive-partitioned-column-logic/57440760#57440760 Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Workaround by changing configuration

```
sql("set spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet = false")
```

Spark docs

"When reading from and writing to Hive metastore Parquet tables, Spark SQL will try to use its own Parquet support instead of Hive SerDe for better performance. This behavior is controlled by the spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet configuration, and is turned on by default."